# How do I apply limits for y-values with curve_fit?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am currently using my beginner-level knowledge of python for some econometric problems I am facing. Until now, this worked perfectly fine. However, my current problem is finding a graph + function for a few interview answers, for example for the following 6 points:

```
xvalues = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
yvalues = [0, 0.15, 0.6, 0.49, 0.51, 1]
```

I've used curve_fit with mixed results. I have no problem with sigmoid and logarithmic functions. But when it comes to polynomial functions, I need to limit the possible y-values the function can have. For 0 <= x <= 1 the following conditions have to apply (I don't care about x < 0 and x > 1):

- 0 <= y <= 1
- Maxima and minima of the function have to be located at said points. This doesn't apply to inflection points, though. Edit for clarity: Maxima and minima have to located **only** at said points.

as a basis, let's take the following, very simple code that works:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def poly6(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    return f * (x ** 6) + e * (x ** 5) + d * (x ** 4) + c * (x ** 3) + b * (x ** 2) + a * (x ** 1)

xvalues = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
yvalues = [0, 0.15, 0.6, 0.49, 0.51, 1]

x = xvalues
y = yvalues

x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
popt, _ = curve_fit(poly6, x, y)
a, b, c, d, e, f = popt
print("Poly 6:")
print(popt)
```

How can I efficiently write these conditions down?

I've tried to find an answer, but with underwhelming success. I found it hard to narrow my problem down to an oneliner that other people already asked.

Comment: Do you care about at which of the said points the extremes are if there are more than 6 points? You have 6 points and want to find a polynomial of degree 6. Then there can be at most 5 extremums. Does it matter which point isn't an extremum?

Comment: @joni no, it doesn't matter. To put that specific condition more bluntly: I need the function to behave between the measured points "as to expect", so no random maximum or minimum between these points.

Comment: @joni I can also use a higher degree than 6 btw, that's no issue. I just intended to have a concrete example at hands.

Comment: Have you thought about using instead of `curve_fit`, using `minimize`? You're supposed to return a value to minimize, which is the error between your model and data. You could add some checks that add huge weights to the residuals in case any of your conditions is invalid, like min/max outside the start/end, or y>1.

Comment: @K.CI yes, this got already recommended but I haven't got the time to try it out (I do that in my free time). I also haven't looked into `minimize` that much, but isn't that an addition to `curve_fit` in this case insteat of a substitution?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's used separately. `minimize` will provide you with a set of values that satisfy that you found the minimum of a function. If that function is your residual, then it's essentially the same as curve_fit. If you provide a more representative set of data for your problem, I will see if I can write some code for you.

Comment: @K.Cl this is the most represantative Set of data available. I'm fully aware of its small size since I'm also researching how little information my questionnaire should contain to provide a satisfying answer for my very specific problem. So it's intentional that it's a very small set of data. But we can artificially increase the data a bit when you add the averages between the points, this should still suffice. Therefore: `xvalues = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]` and `yvalues = [0, 0.075, 0.15, 0.375, 0.6, 0.545, 0.49, 0.5, 0.51, 0.755, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to provide provide bounds of the possible y values of your function. I only implemented the limits of `y` being between 0 and 1. I didn't fully understand what you meant by the maxima/minima of the function having to be in the interval `0 <= x <= 1`. Or do you mean minimum has to be at `x=0` and maximum at `x=1`? If that's the case, then it's fairly easy to add two new weights for those situations.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize, curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvalues = np.array([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
yvalues = np.array([0, 0.075, 0.15, 0.375, 0.6, 0.545, 0.49, 0.5, 0.51, 0.755, 1])

def poly6(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    return f * (x ** 6) + e * (x ** 5) + d * (x ** 4) + c * (x ** 3) + b * (x ** 2) + a * (x ** 1)

def min_function(params, x, y):
    model = poly6(x, *params)
    residual = ((y - model) ** 2).sum()
    
    if np.any(model > 1):
        residual += 100  # Just some large value
    if np.any(model < 0):
        residual += 100

    return residual

res = minimize(min_function, x0=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), args=(xvalues, yvalues))

plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues, label='data')
plt.plot(xvalues, poly6(xvalues, *res.x), label='model')
plt.legend()
```

This is the resulting fit:

[image]

Comment: It works! From here on, I should be able to work out the specifics of my loss function on my own. Thank you!

Comment: And regarding your question with `0 <= x <= 1` 
All rules only have to apply within this range on the x-axis. I don't care if `y < 0` or `y > 1` outside this range.

Answer (score 0):

First, at least your test dataset is very small compared to the amount of variables you are trying to fit.

The constraints for 0<x<1 are:

1. local minima/ maxima at given points y'(x)=0, y''(x)!=0
2. 0<= y(x)<= 1

The first constraint cannot be fulfilled by an approximation approach like curve-fit since you will not end exactly on the given points. Thus you will have to use some interpolation function like `scipy.interpolate.UnivaranteSpline` by definition a spline is continous differentiable and touches all points.

If you are looking for an approximate solution you have to define

- how important is each constraint
- how to measure the deviation of the expected result

and define yourself some kind of loss-function, punishing bad results e.g. `if y >1 return 100000`. Here you should use `scipy.minimize` since it provides the possibility of custom residuum-functions.

---

**Misread the OPs Question**

Second, have a look into the [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) of the module/ function you are useing. Here you see:

> bounds2-tuple of array_like, optional
> Lower and upper bounds on
> parameters. Defaults to no bounds. Each element of the tuple must be
> either an array with the length equal to the number of parameters, or
> a scalar (in which case the bound is taken to be the same for all
> parameters). Use np.inf with an appropriate sign to disable bounds on
> all or some parameters.

Thus, the following change will set a limit for all parameters to `[0,1]`

```
bound=(0,1)
popt, _ = curve_fit(poly6, x, y, bounds=bound)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. He wants to constrain the evaluated polynomial to be within 0 and 1, not the coefficients/parameters.

Comment: I'll try that out. Just a word about your first comment on the small datasize: I'm fully aware of that since I'm also researching how little information my questionnaire should contain to provide a satisfying answer for my very specific problem. So it's intentional that it's a very small set of data.